# FON font not rendinging in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, antialiasing, truetype

When I use a custom font in a web page Chrome (applied using CSS) it is ignored. The font works okay in the OS (Windows) and is of the FON type.

I have found options pointing to switching it to a TTF, however that means it will have anti-aliasing and I do not want any anti-aliasing.

Is there a way to use a FON file in Chrome or is there a tool to convert the FON file to a OTF or TTN file and render it without ant-aliasing?